# Trouble with formatting X axis labels in HighCharts

Tags: pandas, highcharts, justpy

I've been trying to figure this out for a day or two. I'm pretty sure I've typed the exact code from the tutorial I've been watching, but my x axis labels are numbers going from 0 to 1200 in increments of 100. They should be a list of dates provided by the hc.options.xAxis.catagories variable near the bottom of the code. It was my understanding creating this line would create the attribute 'catagories' and fill the x axis labels. I've tried hacking about in the javascript to work around, but to no avail. Can anyone see the issue?

```
import justpy as jp
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import utc

data=pd.read_csv('reviews.csv',parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
data['Day']=data['Timestamp'].dt.date 
day_average=data.groupby(['Day']).mean()


chart_def="""
{
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        inverted: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Atmosphere Temperature by Altitude'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'According to the Standard Atmosphere Model'
    },
    xAxis: {
        reversed: false,
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Altitude'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} km'
        },
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 0 to 80 km.'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.05,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°'
        },
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: -90°C to 20°C.'
        },
        lineWidth: 2
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x} km: {point.y}°C'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enable: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [[0, 15], [10, -50], [20, -56.5], [30, -46.5], [40, -22.1],
            [50, -2.5], [60, -27.7], [70, -55.7], [80, -76.5]]
    }]
}
"""

def app():
    wp=jp.QuasarPage()

    h1=jp.QDiv(a=wp, text='Analysis of Course Reviews',classes='text-h3 text-center q-pa-md')
    p1=jp.QDiv(a=wp,text="These graphs represent course reviews analysis")
    hc=jp.HighCharts(a=wp, options=chart_def)
    hc.options.title.text='Average rating by Day'
    hc.options.xAxis.catagories = day_average.index
    hc.options.series[0].data=list(day_average['Rating'])
    


    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

Comment: Hi @Joe Mcsweeney, Does the title: Average rating by Day' work as expected? What is the result of: `day_average.index`? Live example with your code in pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aLn49dxr/

Comment: Figured it out. I can't spell, 'categories' not 'catagories". FML

Comment: @JoeMcsweeney could you please provide a sample csv file so that we might add this to our example in the justpy codebase and add an answer even if it's just a typo. This is a good example why asking questions via stackoverflow is better than adding issues or questions to justpy github immediately when a problem shows up see https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/discussions/491